# Java addExact method does not detect Integer Overflow when assigned to a variable

Tags: java, integer-overflow

I have the following try block to detect Integer overflow.

```
    try {

        Math.addExact((number % 10) * (int) Math.pow(10, i), reversedNumber);

    } catch(ArithmeticException ae) {

        return 0;

    }
```

Okay, so if i run the above code as is, it causes an ArithmeticException as expected. However, if I want to assign the result of `addExact` to an integer variable, the over flow is never detected.

```
    try {

        reversedNumber = Math.addExact((number % 10) * (int) Math.pow(10, i), reversedNumber);

    } catch(ArithmeticException ae) {

        return 0;

    }
```

Can someone tell me why the exception isn't caught upon assignment to a variable? Is it because the assignment process is itself successful so no exception is thrown?

```
public static int reverse(int x) {

    int number = Math.abs(x);
    if(number == 0) return number;

    int numberOfDigits = (int) Math.log10(number) + 1;
    
    int reversedNumber = 0;
    for(int i = numberOfDigits - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

        try {

            reversedNumber = Math.addExact((number % 10) * (int) Math.pow(10, i), reversedNumber);

        } catch(ArithmeticException ae) {

            return 0;

        }


        number /= 10;

    }

    return x < 0 ? -reversedNumber : reversedNumber;

}
```

with an input of 1534236469 the answer should be 0.

Comment: Can you show a [mcve]? Specifically, what are the values of `number`, `i` and `reversedNumber`?

Comment: @Sweeper https://ideone.com/AvFAqN it should return 0

Comment: Please [edit] the [mcve] into your question, rather than including an external link.

Comment: 0 is a legitimate output. Perhaps you should return -1 on an exception so that you can be sure the exception was thrown? Or some other very unlikely number. Or perhaps put a print statement so that the exception being thrown is visible to you.

Comment: @NomadMaker those are all undesirable, IMO. Better to throw another exception or return Optional.empty().

Comment: I'm just thinking for debugging purposes. Once the reason is known, then the better flows should be allowed. I'd just return an Integer or null, but I'm an old-time programmer. When I was young, we didn't even have negative numbers, let along these new-fangled Optiontionals. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not about whether you assign it to a variable or not. Your method correctly returns 0 for the input 1534236469 *for the wrong reason*, if you don't assign it to `reversedNumber`. For 1534236469, `addExact` does not throw an exception either way.

The *addition* is not overflowing, which is why `addExact` does not throw an exception. But the multiplication of `(number % 10) * (int) Math.pow(10, i)` *is* overflowing. In the first iteration of the loop, you are multiplying `9 * 1000000`, which is out of the range of `int`.

`addExact` only checks the overflow of the addition of the two arguments you pass to it. It does not check the overflow during the evaluation of the two arguments themselves.

You need to use `multiplyExact`:

```
int powerOf10 = (int) Math.pow(10, i);
int digit = (number % 10);
reversedNumber = Math.addExact(Math.multiplyExact(digit, powerOf10), reversedNumber);]
```